# Tell Entity Framework to ignore custom database tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to tell Entity Framework to ignore any custom tables I add to the database. For example, say if I use the sqlmemberhipprovider in the same database as the one used for EF, can I tell EF to just ignore whatever tables I haven't already created classes for? Right now, it's giving the error

"The model backing the 'xxx' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269). "

I don't want EF to do anything on the extra tables it doesn't recognize.

Comment: the initial database was created using code first

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. It wasn't the Membership tables that were causing the problem it was another table I deleted manually that EF was tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your initializer to null?